# SQL Server 2005 - Counter in a select query

Tags: sql-server-2005, counter, select-query

I would like to have a row counter in the select query of my stored procedure, but the counter would not be incremented for each row. The incrementation would depend on the value of one of the fields. Something equivalent to this invalid code:

```
DECLARE @RowIndex as int
SET @RowIndex = 0
SELECT
   f1, f2, f3,
   CASE
      WHEN f1 > 3 THEN @RowIndex += 1
      ELSE @RowIndex
   END AS MyIndex
FROM
   MyTable
```

How should I do that in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in a single query, you'll have to join the table back to itself to get the number or prior rows that meet your criteria.  Also, you definitely need a column that orders the table.  In this case, let's call that column f2.

```
SELECT a.f1, a.f2, a.f3
    , SUM(CASE WHEN b.f1 > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MyIndex
FROM MyTable a
JOIN MyTable b
    ON a.f2 >= b.f2
GROUP BY a.f1, a.f2, a.f3
```

Comment: I will try it. I'm just waiting a little bit to see if other suggestions will be posted (I assume that yours works but I thought that there would be a simpler solution; maybe not after all). By the way, I already have a column that orders the table. Thanks!

Comment: Addendum: I would like a simpler solution because my actual query is MUCH more complicated than the simplified example that I gave.

Comment: Care to share you sample data, because I can't think of any where this does work. See it [not work here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62678/sample-for-9485858-which-doesnt-work)

Comment: This one works for me with a simple table. Now, I will see how to implement it in my actual work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 : I cannot vote for it because I'm a novice here but I would if I could. :-)

Comment: @ConnorsFan Glad I could help.  Love to hear how I earned a downvote on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f1,f2,f3, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY tempf1)-1 AS myIndex
FROM
(
  SELECT f1, f2, f3, CASE WHEN f1>3 THEN f1 ELSE 0 END AS tempf1
  FROM
  MyTable
) AS A
```

Please use Dense_Rank() with order by f1 as above. Try this.

Comment: I tried and SQL Server says that the query is not valid. The main problem for me is assigning a value inside the query. Even without the CASE...END statement, simply saying @RowIndex = 5 as MyIndex makes the query non valid.

Comment: What is the value you need for ELSE part of your CASE statement? is that always 0 or previous value of the variable?

Comment: The counter would be incremented if the condition is met and would stay the same if it is not.